# Irreducibility of an induced rep for discrete groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Physicist here, looking to obtain representations of a discrete group $G$ by the method of induced representations.

If we obtain irreducible representations of subgroup $H \subset G$ and extend it via the method of induced representations to be a representation of the full group $G$, will this induced representation be an irreducible representation of the full group $G$?.

I have no background in pure representation theory so I have no idea how I would proceed if I were to try and show it myself.

Answer (score 0):

No not always: e.g. the trivial representation of $H$ induced to $G$ is always reducible: it has the trivial representation of $G$ as an irreducible constituent.

Comment: But is the trivial representation of $H$ irreducible?

Comment: Yes of course. It has degree $1$ so it would be difficult for it to reduce!

Comment: May I ask if this holds for Lie groups too? I am thinking about the construction of Poincare irreps via the method of induced reps.

Comment: The trivial representation of $G$ has multiplicity $1$ in the induced trivial representation of $H$. And this last one has dimension $|G:H|$. So for a *proper* subgroup we always get a reducible when inducing the trivial one. Yes for Lie groups it is the same construction.